# Suggestions when SharePoint Online site owner/admin cannot delete list item?

Tags: list, error, item-deleted

Error message:

> Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Multiple lists on site, only one being problematic and not allowing any item deletion. Even new items with no relationships to anything cannot be deleted.

- My permission level: full control.
- Can edit items in this list, but not delete.
- No content approval or versioning enabled.
- No workflows associated with list.
- No retention policies defined.

I'm out of ideas. Help?

Comment: Maybe there is some issue with the list. Have you tried to recreate it? (Save as template with content and create new list based on this one?